# Exercise prob. in Lorentz invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

How we do prove that $\langle p\vert q\rangle$ is an invariant by a boost along $z$ axis knowing that:
$$\langle p\vert q\rangle=(2\pi)^3\cdot2\cdot E\cdot\delta(p-q)$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exercise problem in Lorentz invariance](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238715/)

Comment: Hi akram zermane. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the invariance, we replace the energie and the momentum by the values in the new frame. Applying the boost in the z-direction, one gets:

$E'=\gamma E + \beta\gamma p_z$

$p'=\gamma p_z + \beta\gamma E$

And using the following properties of the $\delta$ function:

$\delta( f(x))=\delta (x-x_0)*|f'(x_0)|^{-1}$

And we obtain the invariance.